# Prevalent large (>=90kDa) maintenance protein/loading control

Tags: lab-techniques, western-blot

I was wondering if anyone had recommendations for good, large (hopefully 100kDa+), control proteins that would be present in most mammalian cells.  I'm working mostly with tissue samples from humans and mice, and airway epithelium in particular if that matters.  So far the best I've thought of is HSP90, but that is far from ideal for a number of reasons.  My target proteins are between 125 and 210 kDa.  To improve resolution, we've run pretty much everything under 90kDa off the gel.

That removes the old standbys like actin or GAPDH.  I understand that the protein levels could vary between cell types for a good loading control target.  Bonus points if you know a good antibody clone to it.

Comment: How about RNA polymerase subunits - some of these are large. (In E. coli I used to use beta-beta prime for the same reason. Not particularly abundant but very distinctive.)

Comment: @alanboyd Not a bad idea, I'll give it a try.  Most of these will be testing effects from infections with RNA viruses, so this might look interesting anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vinculin!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculin)  I love our grad-students, I can't believe I didn't think of it last night.

Also, [awesome chart](http://www.abcam.com/primary-antibodies/loading-control-guide), even if it's from a company.

Comment: Thats a pretty useful chart. Bookmarked for later use.

Comment: @Chris I thought about replicating it here, but it seemed too much like stealing